# How can you prevent an device access to a page in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a form manager, like Google Forms, and I need to block an user from answering the same form more than once. At the moment I was thinking about using the user's device IP to redirect him to a "thanks for answering" page. I also was trying to figure out a way to do it with cookies, as it should be less harmful than using IPs (there's all the problem of storing them and it's kinda invasive).

Our app is made in React.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done on backend with blocking the ip for 24hours. Cookies and localstorage at any time could be cleared from developer tools > application > clear all